# I can't run .net core project on mac copied from windows it gives Error CS0116

Tags: .net-core

[image: Visual Studio Screen Shot]

Please i want work on mac, I need this project working on mac.

If i make new project on mac it working fine But problem when copy .net core project from windows to mac, Gives error **CS0116** namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods.

Project.Resources.GlobalUsings.g.cs this file was opened and i can't changed because it is auto-generated.

Comment: You need to use VS for Mac 2022 Preview.

Comment: Thanks it is working, But need to update Nuget package to Nuget 6.1.0

Comment: I get this error in VS for Mac 2019 but VS for Mac 2022 Preview doesn't support .NET 6 Xamarin project yet. Has anyone found a workaround?